# Svgweb unable to animate visibility on initially hidden SVG elements when rendering in Flash

Tags: svg, set, visibility, hidden, svgweb

When trying to get SVG rendering in older IE browsers I've used the svgweb project.
Recently I've come up against bug 585 in svgweb.
https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/issues/detail?id=585&q=visibility

In the following example the rectangle stays hidden in IE but shows after one second in Chrome.

```
    <set xlink:href="#testRect" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="XML" begin="1s" end="2s" from="hidden" to="visible" fill="freeze"/>        
    <rect id="testRect" x="0" y="100" width="300" height="150" fill="#A68064" visibility="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Dynamically setting the fill or stroke of an element before setting the visibility results in the correct behaviour.

```
    <set xlink:href="#testRect" attributeName="fill" attributeType="XML" begin="0s" end="1s" from="#A68064" to="#A68064"/>        
    <set xlink:href="#testRect" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="XML" begin="1s" end="2s" from="hidden" to="visible" fill="freeze"/>        
    <rect id="testRect" x="0" y="100" width="300" height="150" fill="#A68064" visibility="hidden" />
```